# Trouble implementing Natural Number Arithmetic from scratch

Tags: haskell

I've been through LYAH, but I felt it was not a very good introduction to Haskell. I came across "A gentle introduction to Haskell", which recommended Richard Bird's "Introduction to Functional Programming using Haskell". That's the book I'm reading right now. Chapter 3 makes a datatype Nat and implements basic arithmetic with it.

This is the code I have written until now:

```
module Main where
import Prelude hiding ((^^))

data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)
xx :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
m `xx` Zero   = Zero
m `xx` Succ n = (m `xx` n) `add` m

(^^) :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
m ^^ Zero   = Succ Zero
m ^^ Succ n = (m ^^ n) `xx` m

add :: Nat -> Nat -> Nat
m `add` Zero   = m
m `add` Succ n = Succ(m `add` n)

factsu :: Nat -> Nat
factsu Zero     = Succ Zero
factsu (Succ n) = Succ n `xx` factsu n

--Zero = 0

showNat :: Nat -> String
showNat Zero = "Zero"
showNat (Succ Zero) = "Succ Zero"
showNat (Succ (Succ n)) = "Succ (" ++ showNat (Succ n) ++ ")"

main :: IO ()
main = return ()
```

This is what happens:

```
factsu Zero
Succ Zero
it :: Nat
```

How do I define Succ and Zero?

Comment: What do you mean with *define `Succ` and `Zero`*? You defined them in your file...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I think they're being interpreted as strings.

Comment: No, you defined them as: `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`. Since `Nat` is deriving from `Show`, you convert them to a string with `show (Succ Nat)` for instance. You can also derive from `Read` such that you are able to parse `"Succ Zero"` into `Succ Zero`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But I want Zero to equal 0.

Comment: you have to define `show` yourself then.

Comment: @karakfa I don't get how to do that.`Instance Show Nat where`
`Zero = 0`
`Succ n = -- ?`

Comment: Yup, that's about it. I recommend you first implement `div` and `mod` operations, that makes the `Show` instance much easier. (Or you “cheat” by converting to standard `Integer` before showing.)

Comment: @leftaroundabout Wouldn't implementing `div` and `mod` mean I'd have to change my addition, multiplication and exponentiation functions, too?

Comment: If you want `Succ (Succ ... (Succ Zero))` to be written in decimal form, it's easier if you "cheat" and convert that to `Integer` before printing, as leftaroundabout suggests. Writing division/modulo operations for your unary numbers is feasible, but longish. (And no, you don't need to change what you have already written) I'd go for a custom `toInteger` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But I want Zero to equal 0

The underlying issue is what you mean by "I want `Zero` to equal `0`". One literal reading of that might be "I want `Zero == (0 :: Integer)`", but that's impossible, as `Zero` and `0 :: Integer` have different types -- your `Zero` is really its own thing. Nothing stops you, of course, from defining functions that interconvert between them:

```
natToInteger :: Nat -> Integer
integerToNat :: Integer -> Maybe Nat
```

On the other hand, if you just want GHCi to print `Zero` as "0"...

```
GHCi> Zero
0
```

... all you need is a custom `Show` instance, as karakfa and leftaroundabout suggest [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42678254/trouble-implementing-natural-number-arithmetic-from-scratch#comment72481202_42678254). That, however, won't change what `Zero` actually is; you are just changing the way it is displayed.

Finally, a third possibility is that you want to use numeric literal syntax for your `Nat`s:

```
GHCi> 0 + 2 :: Nat
2
it :: Nat
```

That is actually possible if you give `Nat` a `Num` instance. That would probably be a bad idea, though, because `(-)` would be partial and there would be no sensible implementation for `negate` (incidentally, that is also why I put a `Maybe` in the signature of `integerToNat` above). Also, just like in the case of `Show`, adding a `Num` instance wouldn't essentially change what your `Nat`s are -- in particular, at the end of the day numeric literal syntax is just syntax.

<sup>(You might question what I mean by "essentially" if you take the point of view that things are characterised by what you can do with them; but I will stop here before we get too sidetracked.)</sup>

Comment: I definitely mean the third case, I'll try implementing that.

Comment: The third point leaves me wishing `Num` was split into a hierarchy with a `SemiRing`. Something like `class SemiGroup a where { zero :: a, (+) :: a -> a -> a }`, `class SemiGroup a => Group a where { negate :: a -> a, (-) :: a -> a -> a }`, `class SemiGroup a => SemiRing a where { one :: a, (*) :: a -> a -> a }`, `class (SemiRing a, Group a) => Ring a where { fromInteger :: Integer -> a }`, `class Ring a => IntegralDomain a where { div :: a -> a -> a }`.

Comment: @Alec There's always [numeric-prelude](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude) for when you want to discover just how painful a properly fine-grained class hierarchy can be.

Comment: @DanielWagner Yeah - especially with every class named `C`. But even they don't have `SemiRing`.